# Why keyof T doesn't work on a generic object

Tags: typescript

I'd like to have a function with a generic type `T` which must be an object and must have at least a property named `code` of type `string`, and then use `keyof T` to get all object keys.

Why is this invalid?

```
function TableView<T extends { code: string }>() {
    return forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, { data: T[], columns: Columns<keyof T> }>(
        (props, ref) => {
```

Error:

```
TS2344: Type 'keyof T' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

where:

```
export interface Column<T extends string> {
    field: T;
    label: string;
    align?: "left" | "center" | "right"
    format?: "number" | "integer" | "percent" | "timestamp" | "text"
    backgroundColor?: (row: any) => string
}

type Columns<T extends string> = Column<T>[]

export default Columns
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically `T` can have not only `string` keys (`number | symbol` are also allowed). If you want to pick only `string` keys - you can use [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility:

```
const e = Symbol();

type Foo = {
  a: string; // String-like name
  5: string; // Number-like name
  [e]: string; // Symbol-like name
};

type K1 = keyof Foo; // "a" | 5 | typeof e
type K2 = Extract<keyof Foo, string>; // "a"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgM2gdwIZQCYCUCmycAvilBCHAORT4YDGMVAUM-gB6SxzAB2M+KMgb44AYQgAbAK4heAHgAqcDgN7YAznA0wofAOYA+RMzgpg+SdgBccRQG5TcSRgBGl2zr299jsxklgfV4AflsAIklCGHC4AB84cPp8fkFYhPC9fQALGKdUKBAMGDDE3ll3KHTEvgF9NPjEsEFk-mrwmFB8HQxwdoF2PLNXBgBrfXJpdQlJaFKACnI0WwxeAE8ASjgAXmMvA2ZiVhg15vEpWV4NJRVBlM1tXQNjbfOZOSVDAG0AXVZWZBTRjACC8OxuKIANQsaBuqnuWiQ9Ag2HwniePhIhnmWwQTloMGkUDBBUwOAIyHkAAlFABZAAyABFgAA3ACiURAKRgABpEHBsMUMLZFL8+cj3ldbDNLtc2YMoAwYPJRvg1hAiIo+fsfIZjMRsTidsZypJJBtDqxkVd4KJXgBlNYgVxSHGOE5nABiEAgOxM-nR3l8cAA9CG4PaMfoALSBVVwXi9fBOACsgYM9lD4YAchVBLHgPHE1ynF98D90z5M2GI06XZIC0Wk4d3adRABpACMftV6qI3og1fDHvwGpUjXCGGqKeYI7g7YATH75bolSq1WOB9qo4Yh4kp0A)

---

> `Extract<Type, Union>` Constructs a type by extracting from `Type` all union members that are assignable to `Union`

---

Another option suggested by @kaya3 is using `string & keyof T` intersection.

Comment: I tend to use `string & keyof T`, which does the same thing but is (subjectively) more readable.

Comment: @kaya3 Nice! Added to the answer. Let me know if you'd like to flash this as a separate one 

Comment: Not worth making it a separate answer; the main question is "why it doesn't work" which you answered well.

Comment: Thanks very clear! Just to know, is there a way to create a type for an object which forces it to have string keys?

Like `function xxx<T extends ObjectStringKeyOnly>` so that then `keyof T` is a string only.

Comment: @edoedoedo You could do something like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwPLIDYgDwBUA+KAXigGsIQB7AMynyggA9gJkATAZyi4RVRQA-AygAuKAHIA6omAALKNWwhe-NBSpdJAKB0cIAYywBDeNFoBXZIeCJlUAEZmChABTOAXhLhI0mHFcASgkAN2pEDj1neDcAbygARglJNj5JKABfIKgAelyoZGpgKBMsLGoAdwgomPioQ2oDFLTgSQAaUolEzscUxwzsvIKyiuqOIA

Answer (score 1):

Just change `extends string` to `extends any`. It will give you the same result you're looking for. The problem is that `keyof` can be typed as more than just a string.

Comment: You probably mean `'string | number | symbol'`.  You should avoid `any` if possible

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try right now, however I don't fully get the why: I don't want to permit to have an object with a key as a number for example, I want that Columns only allows string as written, and that `T` should contain only object with striny keys so that keyof must be a string. Is there a way?